# How long will a water drop exist until it evaporates based on ambient conditions?

Tags: thermodynamics, water

How long will a water drop exist until it evaporates based on ambient conditions? I am looking for a simple equation or table that would tell me how long a water drop may exist until it evaporates based on ambient conditions (RH, T etc.)

Comment: Hi user. Welcome to Physics.SE. This is not a site ran by an individual user. Instead, a community with a number of users. Okay, What do you really ask? In the title, you've asked for the time period, while in the body - you've asked, *"I'm looking for..."* <-- which makes me think that it's some kinda reference request. What is it? Can you please clarify it for better understanding? ;-)

Comment: If this is a homework question, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem the [Penman equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penman_equation) or some variant thereof would do what you want provided you are interested in open air conditions. It will give you a rate of evaporation with dimensions of mass per unit time per unit surface area. You can use this to set up a differential equation that describes the mass of the drop as a function of time.

Answer (score 0):

The growth or shrink rate of water droplets is determined by the [Mason equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason_equation). This formula takes into account the [Kelvin effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_effect), i. e. the change of vapour pressure due to decreased surface tension at curved water surface.